# Extract values from pattern string, into 3 columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a single column that contains a string in the following pattern:

`blablabla?bla&bla&tv_a=value1&tv_b=value2&tv_3=value3`

I want extract the data from the `tv_[i]` strings into 3 separate columns:

`value1` `value2` `value3`

Example:

For the following two records:

`long-url-here?a=0&b=4&tv_a=hello&tv_b=there&tv_3=now`

`other-url?z=4&v=2&tv_a=this&tv_b=is%20an2&tv_3=example`

Columns should be:

```
column 1 | column 2 | column 3
-------------------------------
hello    | there    | now
this     | is an    | example
```

Comment: ForEach, tv_[i], element {do magic}. But really I am asking you to explain your data. At a point it looks like you are using an array in a looping algorithm, with your tv_[i]. Can you present your data the way you are working it out in excel; using cells? using what so far? blahblahbalh&blah?

Comment: I don't know how I'd do that in Excel, usually I'd dump the column into Notepad++ and use Replace with a regex to search for and replace the matched patterns. Once cleaned up copy and paste the data back into Excel. I could probably offer more assistance if you want to try this route...

Comment: I've edited question to give an example.

Comment: Alright @Mimp, how can I do this in notepad ++? what should i search for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in the first row and change A1 to the first cell:

```
=MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"2",""),"%0"," "),"&tv_",REPT(" ",999)),999*COLUMN(A:A),999)),FIND("=",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"2",""),"%0"," "),"&tv_",REPT(" ",999)),999*COLUMN(A:A),999)))+1,999)
```

Then drag over two more columns and down the length needed.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Nicely done @Scott I'm sure that'd be more efficient than anything I'd kludge together.

Comment: Thanks! however, what if it is not `tv_a` ,`tv_b` etc. but rather `tv_aa`, `tv_abc`, `tv_abcde`? I guess it wouldn't be possible to do in on line of code that can be stretched, therefore, can you explain how to do it per column, per each `tv_something` string?

Comment: @rockyraw then we need to put a find in the formula to find the starting point more dynamically.  See edit.

Answer (score 1):

By use of your example:

> long-url-here?a=0&b=4&tv_a=hello&tv_b=there&tv_3=now

I approach things, "piece wise", or break the problem into smaller parts, then assemble them. That is also known as the "divide and conquer" approach. This is how it looks:

You identified that there are 3 variables in the URL's that interest you, in order:

      **tv_a**, **tv_b**, **tv_3** .But let's let it be: **tv_a**, **tv_bee**, **tv_300000**

Given the URL, lets find tv_a:

     = **FIND(** "tv_a", URL, 1 **)** = **23** = **position** - find the string tv_a in the URL starting at the position of 1st character in the string.

What's the length of the variable, tv_a?

      =**LEN(** "tv_a" **)** = **4** = **length**

Geven the **URL** and the **position** of the first **variable** and the **length** of the variable, lets find the word after the '=' sign:
      =**MID(** URL, variable+length+1, length+1 **)** = **hello**

You can string the whole formula into one single formula. That's a trivial task in Excel. The naming convention in this example is: **url**=A3, **first**=B2, **second**=C2, **third**=D2. This is what is looks like:
[image]
**All Three Variables**: wrt Image above layout

     1st=MID(url,B3+LEN(first)+1,C3-B3-LEN(first)-2)=hello

     2nd=MID(url,C3+LEN(second)+1,D3-C3-LEN(second)-2)=there

     3rd=RIGHT(url,LEN(url)-FIND(third,url,D3)-LEN(third))=now

A trivial task example: using helper-cells

```
Let B3=FIND(first,url,1), C3=LEN(first): preferred
1st=MID(url,B3+LEN(first)+1,C3-B3-LEN(first)-2)=hello
```

```
By substitution, you can use a single line instead of helper-cells:
1st=MID(url,FIND(first,url,1)+LEN(first)+1,FIND(second,url,1)-FIND(first,url,1)-LEN(first)-2)=hello
```

You will find that solving problems like these it's better to use piece-wise solving methods for returning to projects for later use in other similar areas; this way you can see the solving of the problem easier because it's traight forward.

*Naming Convention: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64

Comment: I don't really understand. what is `url`? what is `first`? are these words valid syntax in excel? can you explain which exact line of excel code I should write inside the cell?

Comment: Naming Convention Ref: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64